# How to find derivitive of $\tan(x)$ fraction?

Tags: calculus

I have been doing derivatives but I can't wrap my head around this question for whatever reason. Would appreciate anyone help.
$$g(x) = \tan(x)/e^x$$

Comment: What kind of rules for derivatives do you know? Do you know how to compute the derivative of a product $fg$ where $f$ and $g$ are two differentiable functions?

Comment: Use $\tan x = \sin x / \cos x$ and the derivative of $f (x)/g(x)$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Do you know the quotient rule for finding $\left(\frac{f(x)}{h(x)}\right)'$?

Even better, if you write $g(x) = e^{-x}\tan x$, do you know the product rule for finding $\left(f(x)\cdot h(x)\right)'$?

If you don't know how to find $(\tan x)'$, remember that $\tan x = \sin x / \cos x$ and use the quotient rule mentioned above for that part as well.

Answer (score 0):

You use the quotient rule.

Let $f\left(x\right) = \tan \left(x\right)$

Let $g\left(x\right) = e^x$

The quotient rule says that:

$$\left(\frac{f\left(x\right)}{g\left(x\right)}\right)' = \left(\frac{f'\left(x\right)g\left(x\right)-g'\left(x\right)f\left(x\right)}{\left[g\left(x\right)\right]^2}\right)$$
$$ \left(\frac{\sec ^2\left(x\right)e^x - e^x\tan \left(x\right)}{e^{2x}}\right)$$

---

On a side note: $$\left(e^x\right)' = e^x$$
$$\left(\tan \left(x\right)\right)' = \left(\sec ^2\left(x\right)\right)$$

Comment: *Formatting:* Note you can use `\left` and matching `\right` before parentheses etc to have them automatically grow to accommodate tall expressions: compare $$(\frac12) \textrm{  and  }\left(\frac 12\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

You are going to hae to apply the product rule / quotient rule at least once.  A question is wheter you want to apply it twice

$y = e^{-x} \tan x\\
\frac{dy}{dx} = (\frac {d}{dx} e^{-x}) \tan x + e^{-x}(\frac {d}{dx} \tan x)$

and $\tan x = \frac {\sin x}{\cos x}$

However this is an intersting approch to $\frac {d}{dx} (\tan x)$

[image]

The light blue area is a section of a circle of measure $h$ and radius $\sec x$
The area of this section is $\frac 12 h \sec^2 x$

The light blue area plus the green triangle is a triangle of base $\tan (x+h) - tan x$ and height $1.$  The area is $\frac 12 (\tan (x+h) - tan x)$

and the combined shaded region is a section of a circle of measure $h$ and radius $\sec (x+h)$
The area of this section is $\frac 12 h \sec^2 (x+h)$

$\sec^2 x\le \frac {\tan(x+h) - \tan x}{h} \le \sec^2 (x+h)$

What happens to $\frac {\tan(x+h) - \tan x}{h}$ as $h$ goes to $0$?